Error: Build error: Failed compiling module mime\core.dll How to solve this problem?
I installed lua5.4.2. The system variable path already contains the path. mingw-w64 uses x86_64-14.2.0-release-win32-seh-ucrt-rt_v12-rev0, and luarocks uses LuaRocks 3.11.1.
The following is the error I made when installing Luasocket under Windows 10 system 64-bit. Please give me some guidance. Thank you very much.
C:\Users\40341>luarocks install luasocket
Installing https://luarocks.org/luasocket-3.1.0-1.src.rock

luasocket 3.1.0-1 depends on lua >= 5.1 (5.4-1 provided by VM: success)
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -O2 -c -o src/luasocket.o -IC:\lua\lua54\include src/luasocket.c -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG -DWINVER=0x0501 -Ic:\windows\system32\include
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -O2 -c -o src/timeout.o -IC:\lua\lua54\include src/timeout.c -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG -DWINVER=0x0501 -Ic:\windows\system32\include
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -O2 -c -o src/buffer.o -IC:\lua\lua54\include src/buffer.c -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG -DWINVER=0x0501 -Ic:\windows\system32\include
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -O2 -c -o src/io.o -IC:\lua\lua54\include src/io.c -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG -DWINVER=0x0501 -Ic:\windows\system32\include
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -O2 -c -o src/auxiliar.o -IC:\lua\lua54\include src/auxiliar.c -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG -DWINVER=0x0501 -Ic:\windows\system32\include
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -O2 -c -o src/options.o -IC:\lua\lua54\include src/options.c -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG -DWINVER=0x0501 -Ic:\windows\system32\include
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -O2 -c -o src/inet.o -IC:\lua\lua54\include src/inet.c -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG -DWINVER=0x0501 -Ic:\windows\system32\include
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -O2 -c -o src/except.o -IC:\lua\lua54\include src/except.c -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG -DWINVER=0x0501 -Ic:\windows\system32\include
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -O2 -c -o src/select.o -IC:\lua\lua54\include src/select.c -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG -DWINVER=0x0501 -Ic:\windows\system32\include
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -O2 -c -o src/tcp.o -IC:\lua\lua54\include src/tcp.c -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG -DWINVER=0x0501 -Ic:\windows\system32\include
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -O2 -c -o src/udp.o -IC:\lua\lua54\include src/udp.c -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG -DWINVER=0x0501 -Ic:\windows\system32\include
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -O2 -c -o src/compat.o -IC:\lua\lua54\include src/compat.c -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG -DWINVER=0x0501 -Ic:\windows\system32\include
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -O2 -c -o src/wsocket.o -IC:\lua\lua54\include src/wsocket.c -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG -DWINVER=0x0501 -Ic:\windows\system32\include
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc  -shared -o C:\Users\40341\AppData\Local\Temp\luarocks_build-LuaSocket-3.1.0-1-2988190\socket\core.dll src/luasocket.o src/timeout.o src/buffer.o src/io.o src/auxiliar.o src/options.o src/inet.o src/except.o src/select.o src/tcp.o src/udp.o src/compat.o src/wsocket.o -lws2_32 C:\lua\lua54.dll -lm
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -O2 -c -o src/mime.o -IC:\lua\lua54\include src/mime.c -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG -DWINVER=0x0501 -Ic:\windows\system32\include
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -O2 -c -o src/compat.o -IC:\lua\lua54\include src/compat.c -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG -DWINVER=0x0501 -Ic:\windows\system32\include
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc  -shared -o C:\Users\40341\AppData\Local\Temp\luarocks_build-LuaSocket-3.1.0-1-2988190\mime\core.dll src/mime.o src/compat.o -Lc:\windows\system32 C:\lua\lua54.dll -lm
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/dllcrt2.o:crtdll.c:(.text+0x148): undefined reference to `_execute_onexit_table'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/dllcrt2.o:crtdll.c:(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `_initialize_onexit_table'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/dllcrt2.o:crtdll.c:(.text+0x34b): undefined reference to `_register_onexit_function'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-pseudo-reloc.o):pseudo-reloc.c:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `__acrt_iob_func'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-pseudo-reloc.o):pseudo-reloc.c:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `__acrt_iob_func'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Error: Build error: Failed compiling module mime\core.dll

I get the same error after repeatedly confirming all my package versions and system variable paths

This is weired that luarocks tried to search files from c:\windows\system32\include, how do you configure luarocks? Mabye you should try to run commands in mingw64.
